# using library in java servlet netbean

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, netbeans-7, servlet-filters

i'am using a library have structure below

[image]

i am adding `vn.hus.nlp.tokenizer-4.1.1.jar` file into libraries by `Add JAR/Folder` and copy the rest into my project. it work when i using java application. but when i try servlet, i got problem when using this library.

My project

[image]

Servlet: class `Filter` extends HttpServlet

```
try {          
       VietTokenizer v = new VietTokenizer(); // error here !
       JSONObject jso=new JSONObject();
       jso.put("status","A");
       jso.put("label","true");
       out.print(jso);
    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
```

log

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Filter] in context with path [/BadwordFilter] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    at badword.filter.Filter.processRequest(Filter.java:51)
    at badword.filter.Filter.doGet(Filter.java:74)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**`json-simple-1.1.1.jar is work well.`**
thank you!

Comment: you have a dependency on `org.apache.commons.cli`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `commons-cli` library. You can find it for example here, included in the archive in the lib folder:

https://code.google.com/p/vntagger-gate-plugin/source/browse/lib/vn.hus.nlp.tokenizer-4.1.1.jar

You can add it the same way you added the first library.

Comment: thank you. i am added it but still have error. it will be okie if call this lib from main ( java application), but when i call it from servlet. it have this problem

Comment: That's quite strange, since the servlet does not have problem finding the `VietTokenizer` class, which is in the library added the same way as commons...

Answer (score 1):

I think, library don't import in libs when you deploy
Right click on your web project, select **Libraries**. In **Complie** Tab, make sure your library was checked!